# How do I remove sidebars from wordpress websites?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have tried a multitude of different options but I still can't remove the ugly, garbage, useless sidebar from my wordpress site.

I can enter some code, if I knew even where to start but as it is right now I'm at wits end and I don't know what else to do. I am willing to work with the PHP but I just don't know how and every single thing I've run into online is either incorrect or involves downloading a theme that uses a checkbox.

Comment: do you want to remove from page or post ??

Comment: have you using child theme ??

Answer (score 1):

If you are really desparate to do this and do not have experience/skills in wordpress development you could search through all current theme files and remove every:

```
<?php get_sidebar('someTextSpecificForEverySidebar'); ?>
```

and

```
<?php dynamic_sidebar('someTextSpecificForEverySidebar'); ?>
```